# Adding a scale to Plotly express map

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I am plotting the coordinates of a vehicle obtained from an NCOM/CSV file using the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\SASWATIK\depthai-python\ClientPython\Trial1\Plot.csv")

color_scale = [(0, 'orange'), (1, 'red')]

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
                        lat="Latitude (deg)",
                        lon="Longitude (deg)",
                        hover_name="Time (GPS s)",
                        zoom=8,
                        height=800,
                        width=1600)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={'r':0, 't':0, 'l':0, 'b':0})
fig.show()
```

I am getting [the attached map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDCB6.png). I want to add a scale to the map so as to visualize the metric distance of the traced path.

I searched stack overflow and found no answers, tried to use Dash but Dash isn't running... it was giving the error:

> importerror: cannot import name 'get_current_traceback' from 'werkzeug.debug.tbtools' (c:\users\saswatik\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)